# Does an index where the last column is unique and already indexed make sense?

Tags: sql-server, index

I found a unique index on `(RetailerID, ID)` in our database.  The `ID` column is the primary key so it's already uniquely indexed.  I can't see how an index on `(RetailerID, ID)` could help when looking up an individual record by `RetailerID` *and* `ID` (or just `ID`).

I suspect it might be helpful when querying all the `ID`s under a particular `RetailerID`, since it covers such a query.  Is that true?

But then why not just make the index on `RetailerID` include `ID`?  Perhaps the unique index on `(RetailerID, ID)` covers the query in the same way but performs better as a result of being a unique index.

---

As I said, there's a unique primary clustering key on `ID` alone.  There's also a unique index on `(RetailerID, ID)`. Since `ID` is already unique, querying `where RetailerID = x and ID = y` shouldn't be any more efficient than simply querying `where ID = y`.  `(ID)` is unique and `(RetailerID, ID)` is unique, so `ID` is associated with at most one `RetailerID`.  Therefore, if a predicate has `ID,` then including `RetailerID` in the predicate is redundant.  The clustered index would always be faster.

An index on `(RetailerID, ID)` could be helpful for a query where the predicate is *just* on `RetailerID` and the select is on *just* `ID`, because it would cover the query, but for queries where `ID` is in the predicate, `RetailerID` in the predicate is redundant, and since it has no other included columns, it would be less-efficient than the clustered index when selecting any column other than `ID`.  That's why I'm not seeing the point of this index, given the predicates used (which always involve `ID`).

Comment: I imagine that it was a mistake to make it a unique index, but someone wanted to speed up searches for specific RetailerID's.  But completely unnecessary if also specifying the ID in the predicates.

Comment: unique index on (RetailerID, ID) will be called Composite Non cluster Index which in no way is equal to covering index.so when you query on where (Retailerid=?) or (RetailerID=? and ID=?) then you get benefit of index.since your case if like ROFL so you get index benefit even when you query only on id=? since id is seperately indexed.IMHO, one of two unquie key will be CI and other will be NCI.Or make both of them Composite CI

Answer (score 3):

I can think about one scenario where such index is needed. If you want another table to have a Foreign Key constraint that refers `(RetailerID, ID)`, you must create a unique constraint (index).  This pattern makes sense in some cases, for instance if you want to have a common parent table which holds common attributes, and multiple detail tables, and at the same time enforce that details are saved in the proper table.

**Update**. Example to illustrate an idea  :

```
vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id, year, model, ...
         PK (vehicle_id),  
         Unique (vehicle_type_id,car_id),
         CHECK (vehicle_type_id IN ('car','truck'))
);  

car (vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id default 'car', 
     num_passengers, car_type, ....
     PK,FK(vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id) ref vehicle, 
     CHECK (vehicle_type_id ='car')
); 

truck (vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id default 'truck',  load, 
     dimensions, ... ,  
     PK,FK(vehicle_id, vehicle_type_id) ref vehicle, 
     CHECK (vehicle_type_id ='truck')
);
```

Thus you enforce that truck's attributes are always stored in truck table, car's - in car, and at the same time refer to `vehicle` if vehicle type is not important, say `vehicle_owner`  can look like `vehicle_id, person_id, date_from ,date_thru, FK (vehicle_Id) ref vehicle(vehicle_id))`.

Answer (score 2):

Clustered index columns are automatically added to non clustered index. Once non clustered key is located if other column values are required (by your query, most likely due select columns) to be retrieved a row locator is used to located the data row. In your case that is column ID. If it is a heap a unique pointer is added, which points to the pageid, rowid.

You can add columns to avoid going to data rows in your non clustered index as included column. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-indexes-with-included-columns).

[Below is from books online:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described)

> Nonclustered indexes have a structure separate from the data rows. A
>   nonclustered index contains the nonclustered index key values and each
>   key value entry has a pointer to the **data row** that contains the
>   key value.
>
> The pointer from an index row in a nonclustered index to a data row is
>   called a row locator. The structure of the row locator depends on
>   whether the data pages are stored in a heap or a clustered table. For
>   a heap, a row locator is a pointer to the row. For a clustered table,
>   **the row locator is the clustered index key**.

Here is a [demo](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/08/clustered-index-key-columns-in-nonclustered-indexes/) of this by Brent Ozar.

Comment: Regarding the first point if `Id` is the CI key then the index in the Q will be identical to a non unique one on `(RetailerID)` as for non unique non clustered  indexes the CI key gets implicitly added to the NCI keys.

Comment: Yeah, this post isn't telling me anything I don't already know; that's why I'm asking the question.  My whole point is that ID is already the primary clustering key, so an index on (RetailerID, ID) seems redundantly over-specific when ID alone is sufficient to uniquely identify the row.  Again, since it's non-clustered, it seems it would add an additional level of indirection as it has to locate the data row, unlike the primary key clustered index which wouldn't have to do so. My point is, I'd *have* to already know everything that's in this post to even have the insight to form the question.